# SAP UI5 -Add Custom colors to SAP Viz chart lines graph based on measures?

Tags: sapui5

Visit the website  https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/vizdocs/index.html regarding Viz docs.

PFB Solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
var oVizFrame = new sap.viz.ui5.controls.VizFrame(this._constants.vizFrames.config);

oVizFrame.setVizProperties({
  plotArea: {
    line: {
      lineRenderer: function(oevent) {
        if (oevent.ctx.measureNames === "Capacity_Utilization_Percent") {
          oevent.graphic.color = "#fac364";
        } else {
          oevent.graphic.color = "#d998cb";
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```